# Servlet still passes data on page refresh

Tags: jsp, servlets, refresh

After I insert to the database through a servlet, i redirect the page to the "home" page. However, when i refresh, data is still passed and duplicates in the DB arise.

The system flow goes like this: I load a page wherein projects are listed, when i click a project, i change a div in a page to show a textarea for comments. When i click on submit comment, the values are inserted to the database and the page is redirected to the page without the list of projects. However when i refresh, data is still passed.

Would anyone know how I can actually remove the data or not pass data on refresh? Thank you!

Comment: When you refresh the page, what is the url on the address bar? Is the browser asking you to re-submit the form ?

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms indicate that you were actually *forwarding* the request to the home JSP, not redirecting. With a real [redirect after post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), this problem should not occur at all.

So, make sure that you're really performing a redirect as follows

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/home.jsp");
```

and thus not a forward as follows

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: This won't work if user want to pass data request attributes.

Comment: Just include it in the redirect URL then.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable situation is after submitting first request, the url in browser is changed and it indicate to servlet-URL.So when you hit the refresh button it directly call to servlet hence the same process execute again.
for example -

your current browser url is  -- www.myurl.com/mypage.jsp

and request url is www.myurl.com/mypage.action(indicate to servlet)

after submitting the first request the url in browser would be www.myurl.com/mypage.action

so whenever you refresh page it directly call to servlet.

Solution is  - redirect the jsp page again in servlet after completing the request.